# Categorize Jasmine or Mocha tests suites or cases to run a subset of all tests

Tags: jasmine, protractor, mocha.js, subset, cypress

I'am looking for a way to categorize test cases or test suites into categories for different testing enviroments like localhost, mock-stage  or prelive. I want to use these categories to puts all tests into subgroups that can be run all at once when needed.

All I found so far ist the skip(); function in Mocha.

I used it to create a enviroment like this:

**preconditions.js**

```
  export function onlyLocal () {

  if (type != "local" ) {
    this.test.parent.pending = true;
      this.skip();
  }
}
```

Plus some functions like login(user) and logout()

**some_spec.js**

```
import * as logins from './preconditions';


describe('This runs only on localhost', function () {

  context('Some Test', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
      preconditions.onlyLocal()
      preconditions.login('user1')

    })

    afterEach(function () {

      preconditions.onlyLocal()
      preconditions.logout()
    })


    it('Some test that only runs local', function () {
      preconditions.onlyLocal();
      /*test stuff here*/


    })
  })
})
```

This works very bad and has to be done in beforeeach,aftereach and the test itself. 
 What I want is something that blocks the whole test when used in the beforeach part or a way to categorize a whole test suite. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the protractor config you have the ability to define `suites`. You can setup some files external to your config and place different tests in the suites based on the environment they will be running against.

Example:

```
//suite.localhost.js
exports.suites {
  login: 'login.spec.js',
  smoke: ['smoke1.spec.js', 'smoke2.spec.js']
};

//suite.mock-stage.js
exports.suites {
  login: 'login.spec.js',
  smoke: ['some-other-smoke.spec.js', 'another-smoke.spec.js' ]
}
```

This way you will have all of your suites categorized by environment. Now, in order to run them you will need to pass in an environment flag. Say you use `params.env` as your flag. You would run them from the command line like this

```
protractor conf.js --params.env=localhost --suite smoke
```

Now in your `onPrepare` you have access to this environment flag and can define suites based on what flag is passed in.

```
onPrepare: function() {
  switch(browser.params.env)
    case 'localhost':
      browser.suites = require('suite.localhost').suites;
      break;
    case 'mock-stage':
      browser.suites = require('suite.mock-stage').suites;
    //and so on...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot now I know what documention I can read to come further! I guess it is possible to put a file in many suites isn't it? there are many tests that can be run on all levels and just have a diferent login process that can be changed with a simple if funktion based on the flag.

Comment: Yeah, you can put the same file in as many suites as you like. Also, I have done this same thing with `browser.params` so that my login credentials and other global variables I use can be imported per environment as well.